# background color for row with multiple boxes

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I want to set background color for whole row, here is what I did now:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Column(
        [
            [sg.pin(sg.Text('Values', background_color='lightblue', font=('Helvitica 13 bold'))), 
             sg.pin(sg.T("$",font=('Helvitica 13 bold'), background_color='lightblue')),
             sg.pin(sg.Text("100", background_color='lightblue'))]
        ],
    )]
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Since it has 3 text boxes, there are some blank in between. Is there a way to set color for the entire row while keeping the 3 text boxes rather than make it one? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's no option for the background color of `sg.pin`, try to define one for it.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def pin(elem, vertical_alignment=None, expand_x=None, expand_y=None):
    return sg.Column([[elem, sg.Column([[]], pad=(0,0))]], pad=(0, 0), vertical_alignment=vertical_alignment, expand_x=expand_x, expand_y=expand_y, background_color=elem.BackgroundColor)

layout = [
    [sg.Column(
        [
            [pin(sg.Text('Values', background_color='lightblue', font=('Helvitica 13 bold'))),
             pin(sg.T("$",font=('Helvitica 13 bold'), background_color='lightblue')),
             pin(sg.Text("100", background_color='lightblue'))]
        ],
    )]
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: I struggle to come there to search for needed changes.  I seem to do the 2 locations badly so going to focus on GH only and hope what's learned eventually comes back to the project.